# MS Access Expression used to link to an image

Tags: ms-access

I have quite a simple issue that is baffling me.

I'm building a product database, simple enough, but I'm having issues with automatically pulling in the product images.

All images reside on a server with a standard naming convention.  [SKU#]_Main.jpg, [SKU#]_AV.jpg, [SKU#]_AV1.jpg, etc.

They all reside in one of two folders: w:\Photos\02 Gear\High Res\  or W:\Photos\01 Apparel\High Res\

These paths are used to populate data sheets for upload to our online retailers.

Wanting to make product data entry for all these image paths automatic I created the following:

FilePath list box with the two path choices. 
Textboxes: Main, AV, AV1 etc. that are automatically populated with this expression:  =[FilePath] & [SKU] & "_AV.jpg" ( the "_AV" changing for each variant.

Then, image boxes look to the textboxes for the filepath and displays the image.

If the filepath is just typed into the Main, AV, etc fields the image box populates.  If I use the expression it doesn't, even though the text in the Main, AV, etc fields are identical.  [image: Sample of Image issue]

In the image the first 3 lines are typed in.  The image boxes populate.  The next lines have the expression.  By all outward appearances the file path 'looks' the same.  But it won't pull the image.

So what obvious piece am I missing?  I know I'm going to feel like an idiot once one of you kind folk answer  :)

Comment: See nothing wrong with expressions. Since we don't have your db and images, cannot reproduce situation. You are using Image control? Technique has worked for me. Although I put the expression to build the path directly in Image control ControlSource.

Comment: Yea, that was the simple answer that eluded me... put the expression in the image control :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably fighting with the hyperlink syntax and may have to use *HyperlinkPart*:

```
CleanUrl = HyperlinkPart(SavedUrl, acAddress)
```

I wrote an article dealing with this (and more):

[Show pictures directly from URLs in Access forms and reports](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29679/Show-pictures-directly-from-URLs-in-Access-forms-and-reports.html)

A working demo is for download at that page.

Comment: @Rene: Thanks! Appreciated.

Comment: I'm not dealing with hyperlinks in this instance, but I will be in another and this code will be amazingly useful.  Thanks!

I did find the 'simple' answer that had been eluding me.  Even though I need the file path for other things (and hence the separate field to capture it) rather than having the image box look to the file path texbox I can simply put the =[FilePath] & [SKU] & "_AV.jpg" expression in the Image texbox and it works fine.  


Sorry for the delayed response to your quick answer... I had the current bug that is going around and have been out of the office until today.

Comment: @Cryndalae: No problem. Please vote up if you feel so.

Comment: Just up voted for you.  Since I'm new here it doesn't display :(  But thanks!

Comment: @Cryndalae: It's the large up/down triangles to the top-left of the answer.

Comment: Yes, did that.  Got a message it wouldn't show live as I'm new and it was my 1st up vote.  My up votes won't show until I've made 15 posts or some such.

Comment: @Cryndalae: Ah, yes, there are some bumps initially.